# Rails 4 nested resource create method does not post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to set up a simple product review platform and am having trouble getting the "add a review" functionality to work. In my app, resources are being reviewed.

routes.rb:

```
  resources :resources do
    resources :reviews, only: [:new, :create]
  end
```

I've set up my associations as follows:

resource.rb:

```
class Resource < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reviews, dependent: :destroy

  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 100 }, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  validates :location, length: { maximum: 100 }
  validates :description, presence: true, length: { maximum: 500 }
end
```

review.rb:

```
class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :resource

  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :resource_id, presence: true
  validates :rating, presence: true
  validates :review, presence: true, length: { maximum: 5000 }
end
```

reviews_controller.rb:

```
class ReviewsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_resource

  def new
    @review = @resource.reviews.build
  end

  def create
    @review = @resource.reviews.build(review_params)
    if @review.save
      flash[:success] = "Thank you! Your review has been added."
      redirect_to new_resource_review_path
    else
      flash[:error] = "Something went wrong. Please try again."
      redirect_to new_resource_review_path
    end
  end

  private

  def set_resource
    @resource = Resource.find(params[:resource_id])
  end

  def review_params
    params.require(:review).permit(:rating, :review)
  end
end
```

And finally my view form_for:

```
<%= form_for [@resource, @review] do |f| %>
    Rating: <%= f.text_field :rating, placeholder: "Rating (1-5)" %>
    Review: <%= f.text_area :review, placeholder: "A detailed review of your experience with this resource.", rows: 5 %>
    <%= f.submit "Submit"%>
<% end %>
```

When I use the form to submit a dummy review (let's say the rating=5 and the review=good), my console displays the following:

```
Started POST "/resources/2/reviews" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-22 17:04:32 -700
Processing by ReviewsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",  "authenticity_token"=>"VgzFev7EeEmMFOvjY62hEx8S7dh+pWyyFrf7s4GmKVc=", "review"=> {"rating"=>"5", "review"=>"good"}, "commit"=>"Submit", "resource_id"=>"2"}
```

So it appears the nested routes are wired such that it should work, however submitting the form just displays the flash error with no further explanation of what else needs to be done. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out after consulting the good folks at the #RubyOnRails IRC channel. Turns out I wasn't passing in a user_id when I had it being validated in the review model...

Edited the code in my strong parameters method and got it to work:

```
def review_params
  params.require(:review).permit(:rating, :review).merge(user_id: current_user.id)
end
```

(I'm using Devise which gives me the current_user helper.)